# How does the UX differ between Aurora dapps and NEAR dapps?

Tags: nearprotocol, rainbow-bridge, aurora-evm, aurora-near

I wanted to understand the difference in UX if the Dapp is deployed using Aurora (EVM) or using Rust? Do the user wallet transactions work the same way? Or the users have to interact with Aurora apps differently than the other apps on Near built using Rust?

Answer (score 2):

[Aurora](https://aurora.dev) provides both an Ethereum Virtual Machine (EVM) compatibility layer on top of the NEAR blockchain, as well as Web3-compatible JSON-RPC endpoints that any Ethereum client can connect to and interact with.

This means that users interact with Aurora dapps in the same way and using the same exact tooling as they interact with Ethereum dapps.

Key pairs and wallet balances on Aurora are distinct from those on NEAR. Instead of the NEAR Wallet, you'd use MetaMask (or any other Ethereum wallet). Instead of the NEAR Explorer, there is the Aurora Explorer.

Using the Rainbow Bridge, you can easily transfer ETH balances and ERC-20 token balances between Ethereum, NEAR, and Aurora in any combination. So, interoperability between dapps built on NEAR and those built on Aurora is possible, but not automatic.